# Java: Splitting array/list of elements into sublists of equal elements

Tags: java, list, split

Given a sorted List as such:

`List<Integer> a = Arrays.asList(1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 5, 5, 7);`

Would there be a single-line way of splitting this array into sublists, each containing elements of equal value, eg:

`List[List[1, 1, 1], List[2], List[4], List[5, 5], List[7]]`

Answer (score 7):

You can stream over the elements of the `List` and use `Collectors.groupingBy()` to group identical elements. It will produce a `Map<Integer,List<Integer>>`, and you can obtain the `values()` `Collection`:

```
Collection<List<Integer>> grouped =
    a.stream()
     .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity()))
     .values();
```

To get a `List<List<Integer>>` you can use:

```
List<List<Integer>> grouped = 
    new ArrayList<> (a.stream()
                      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity()))
                      .values());
```

The second snippet produces the `List`:

```
[[1, 1, 1], [2], [4], [5, 5], [7]]
```